# Calling a method of a Rails Engine from Main App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I have a Rails engine and have the following in the {Rails_engine}/lib/role_authorization/session_user.rb

```
  module RoleAuthorization
        class SessionUser
          mattr_accessor :current_user, :role

        def current_user(user)
          current_user = user
        end

        def roles(role)
          role = roles
        end      
       end
      end
```

I am calling the following methods from the main_application
{main_app}/errors/application_errors.rb

```
class ApplicationErrors

    def self.access_denied error, controller

     RoleAuthorization::SessionUser.current_user(current_user)

    end
```

However i am getting an undefined method current_user here . Does anybody have any idea what i am doing here

Comment: You could try with ::RoleAuthorization::SessionUser.current_user(current_user)

Answer (score 1):

```
RoleAuthorization::SessionUser.current_user
```

Is undefined because you defined `current_user` as an instance method on the SessionUser class. Without knowing exactly how you're using this class in the rest of the system these following suggestions could work but break something else:

```
RoleAuthorization::SessionUser.new.current_user(current_user)
```

or add self to the method declaration in SessionUser:

```
module RoleAuthorization
  class SessionUser
    class << self
      attr_accessor :current_user, :role

      def current_user(user = nil)
        self.current_user ||= user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Notice I changed `mattr_accessor` to `attr_accessor`. This is because the former is for Modules only and you're calling it within a class. Then I open up the singleton class with `class << self` so I can define current_user as a class method and use attr_accessor to access class instance variables. Assigning user to self.current_user will now make it available for access via: `RoleAuthorization::SessionUser.current_user`